# Elegant or idiomatic way to null check multiple arguments for method

Tags: java

I have a method like below for creating a POJO and populating a parent object with a field for the said POJO

```
public void createMyPOJO(
      ParentObject parentObject,
      Boolean i,
      Boolean j,
      Boolean k) {
    if (i != null || j != null || k != null) {
      MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo();
      if (i != null) myPojo.setIndicatorI(i);
      if (j != null) myPojo.setIndicatorJ(j);
      if (k != null) myPojo.setIndicatorK(k);

      parentObject.setMyPojo(myPojo);
    }
  }
```

Using Optional types or @Nullable will only clutter this, and using a data type like Boolean[] also does not really feel like much of an improvement. What is a more idiomatic or elegant way to avoid null checking basically every single line?

Comment: There isn't really any better option.  Sorry.

Comment: Unless you're willing to go down the `createMyPOJO(ParentObject parent, Boolean... flags)` route, but then you're going to need something for validating and resolving "which boolean is which flag". Capturing those bools their own object, and passing that around, with a `void setIndicators(ParentObject)` that sets the appropriate things might be just as much code, if not nore, but would probably at least be cleaner.

Comment: have your `setIndicatorI()` method do the null check... that way you can call `myPojo.setIndicatorI(null)` and nothing will happen

Comment: Or even create a constructor for `MyPojo` and do the same thing as above ^^

Comment: Unfortunately I do not get to touch MyPojo since it's from an external library in my case

Comment: As an aside they warn against using nullable `Boolean`object references for tri-state logic because it’s easy to forget the null check in this case (I have used them myself).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `boolean` instead of `Boolean` and let the [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) do the work for you (use `false` instead of `null` when calling `createMyPOJO(...)`). This also removes the null-check validation.

```
public void createMyPOJO(
        ParentObject parentObject,
        boolean i,
        boolean j,
        boolean k) {
    if (i || j || k) {
        MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo();
        if(i) myPojo.setIndicatorI(i);
        if(j) myPojo.setIndicatorJ(j);
        if(k) myPojo.setIndicatorK(k);

        parentObject.setMyPojo(myPojo);
    }
}
```

Optionally you could add a [builder](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern) to `MyPojo` class and use it for building new instances of `MyPojo`.

**EDIT:**

As requirements have grown and each indicator should support `null`, `true` and `false` values I think the best solution is to use a builder.

```java
public class MyPojoBuilder {

    private Boolean indicatorI;
    private Boolean indicatorJ;
    private Boolean indicatorK;
    private ParentObject parentObject;

    private MyPojoBuilder(ParentObject parentObject) {
        this.parentObject = parentObject;
    }

    public static MyPojoBuilder withParentObject(ParentObject parentObject) {
        return new MyPojoBuilder(parentObject);
    }

    public MyPojoBuilder withIndicatorI(Boolean value) {
        indicatorI = value;
        return this;
    }

    public MyPojoBuilder withIndicatorJ(Boolean value) {
        indicatorJ = value;
        return this;
    }

    public MyPojoBuilder withIndicatorK(Boolean value) {
        indicatorK = value;
        return this;
    }

    public void build() {
        if (indicatorI == null && indicatorJ == null && indicatorK == null) {
            // Throw some exception instead???
            return;
        }

        if (parentObject == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ParentObject cannot be null");
        }

        MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo();
        myPojo.setIndicatorI(indicatorI);
        myPojo.setIndicatorJ(indicatorJ);
        myPojo.setIndicatorK(indicatorK);

        parentObject.setMyPojo(myPojo);
    }
}
```

The builder could be extended to create and return a new `ParentObject` instance if required.

**Usage example**

```java
ParentObject parentObjectWithIndicatorIAndK = new ParentObject();

MyPojoBuilder.withParentObject(parentObjectWithIndicatorIAndK)
        .withIndicatorI(true)
        .withIndicatorK(false)
        .build();

System.out.println(parentObjectWithIndicatorIAndK);
```

**Output**:

```
ParentObject{myPojo=MyPojo{indicatorI=true, indicatorJ=null, indicatorK=false}}
```

Here is a [demo project](https://github.com/Martin-BG/builder-pattern-example) implementing the concept.

Comment: You will get a NullPointer if Boolean's are passed in as null

Comment: I want to be able to leave fields as null if their corresponding indicators come in as null, or set to true or false if they have a value. Would this not skip that whole block if i,j,k are all false?

Comment: @RobOhRob I was under the impression that `createMyPOJO(...)` is user created and will be used by the application for the build the `MyPojo` which is an external dependency, so no `null`'s would be passed in as method arguments.

Comment: @VictorS All Object field are by default `null`, so a simple check like `if(i)` before setting each indicator should do the trick. I'll update my answer

Comment: @MartinBG i,j,k are booleans though. I want them to be set when they come in false also. Your example sets them only when they come in true

Comment: @VictorS It's a strange requirement to set and use a Boolean filed in all 3 states (null, true and false). :) In that case I think a more sane solution is to use a `Builder` as it allows you to set only the fields you want. I've created a demo project around the idea (see updated answer for details)